# How to send model attribute to spring controller

Tags: spring, postman

I want to test my controller using postman but don't know how to send a model attribute using postman. I even don't know whether it is possible or not.

My Controller seems like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1")
public class PaymentController {

@Autowired
private CredentialsRepository credentialsRepository;

@PostMapping(path = "/charge")
public String charge(@ModelAttribute("pay-load") PayLoad payLoad, Model model) {
    Credentials creds = credentialsRepository.findCredentialsById(1);

    if (creds == null)
        return "init_credentials";

    return "charge";
  }
}
```

Model Attribute

```
public class PayLoad {
  private Integer mId;
  private Integer ordId;
  private Integer cardId;
  private Integer cvvNo;
  private String hash;
// getter & setter
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

I found the way to send model attributes to the spring controller.
see above screenshot for your reference.

Comment: If a field is not a string/integer, but instead a file, how do we do that in Postman?

Answer (score 0):

Even you can pass all the key and value in requestParam from postman.
Instead of requestBody. ModelAttribute object treat each and every key and value as requestParam. It's just a way to combine a lot of requestParam in one object. Even you can try out with curl request, so it will make you more clear.

Thanks